# /Date(1381363200000)/ to get Simple Date object from this web service reponse?

Tags: android, date

I have get web service response in my android app in json format. In this response I need to find a date from json. I am getting date `"/Date(1381363200000)/"` in this format, now to have to convert it to JAVA date object and then get a simple date like : "20-june-2013". I have done some r&d in Google I found about Gson but I be more confused. Please any body tell me how can I achieve this.

Thank you in advance...

Comment: You seem to be looking for converting timestamp to date.  Try searching, numerous examples should exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The date is in [epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_%28reference_date%29) format. All you need to do, is convert it from epoch into a human readable date.

Here's an example of how to do it in Java

```
Date date = new Date(1381363200000);
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
String formatted = format.format(date);
System.out.println(formatted);
```

HTH